# Import Text File into Excel Using VBA to the table without refresh everything away

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub ImportTextFile()
Dim rPaht As String
Dim rFileName As String
rPaht = Sheet1.Range("C9")
rFileName = Sheet1.Range("C10")
Range("G8").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Clear

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & rPaht & "\" & rFileName & ".txt", Destination:= _
    Range("$g$9"))
    .Name = Sheet1.Range("C10").Value
    .TextFilePlatform = 874
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileOtherDelimiter = ":"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Sheet1.Range("C9") = rPaht
Sheet1.Range("C10") = rFileName
End Sub
```

this is code that i used. i got the problem that every time i import some text file in to the table it clear away every thing on table include table line and format

i want to ask if there anyway to import text file to the area that we want without harming the other cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the file scripting object to read in a text file instead.   This example uses late binding but you can also early bind it.  It would be more efficient to read to a variable and then set that variable to the outputrange.

```
Sub ImportTextFile()
   Dim rPath As String, rFileName As String, fs As Object, fsFile As Object, iLine As Integer

   rPath = Sheet1.Range("C9")
   rFileName = Sheet1.Range("C10")
   Range("G8").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Clear

   'Use filescripting object to open the file on Windows
   Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set fsFile = fs.OpenTextFile(rPath & "\" & rFileName, 1, False)

    'Loop through the file
   Do While fsFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
       iLine = iLine + 1

       Sheet1.Cells(iLine + 8, 1) = VBA.Split(fsFile.ReadLine, vbTab)
   Loop

   Set fs = Nothing
   Set fsFile = Nothing
End Sub
```